# Sentiment analysis for a data

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe in which every row is a text in which I would like to implement sentiment analysis with positive or negative results.

I made the appropriate cleaning to the text removing the stopwords, stemmining, punctuation, lower case letters etc.

Is there any simple example from where I could start to take a positive or negative results?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this answer is way too late after looking at the date of the OP's question but for others who might stumble here, I am also a beginner in sentiment analysis, but found [this link](https://pythonspot.com/en/python-sentiment-analysis/) to be quite a good simple start. The example is in Python but others exist for other languages as well.

EDIT: to add relevant information from the linked page:

The example uses training and prediction to analyse sentences. Each sentence is converted into words and each word is then converted into a feature and then tokenised.

This is the whole code with minor changes:

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import names

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

# define vocabularies
positive_vocab = [ the list of all your positive words ]
negative_vocab = [ the list of all your negative words ]
neutral_vocab = [ the list of all your neutral words ]

# convert each word into features
positive_features = [(word_feats(pos), 'pos') for pos in positive_vocab]
negative_features = [(word_feats(neg), 'neg') for neg in negative_vocab]
neutral_features = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu') for neu in neutral_vocab]

train_set = negative_features + positive_features + neutral_features

# train the classifier
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set) 

# Predict
neg = 0
pos = 0
sentence = "In another life, you should be an aspiring poet or a martyr"
sentence = sentence.lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')
for word in words:
    classResult = classifier.classify( word_feats(word))
    if classResult == 'neg':
        neg = neg + 1
    if classResult == 'pos':
        pos = pos + 1

print('Positive: ' + str(float(pos)/len(words)))
print('Negative: ' + str(float(neg)/len(words)))
```

Comment: Welcome to our site! We are wary of link-only answers because they will have no value if the link "rots" (the URL changes or the material is removed from the web altogether). Do you think you could give a brief summary of what the link is saying? Alternatively we can convert this into a comment for you

Comment: Added code and some information. Hope that is ok.